# Why does Ansible sometimes not sync files when SSH pipelining is turned on?

Tags: ansible

I turned on Ansible SSH pipelining to speed things up:

```
[connection]
pipelining = True
```

After this a task that has been successfully running for months has started to fail intermittently:

```
- name: 'Create configuration file'
  copy:
    src: server.cfg
    dest: /etc/server/server.cfg
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0600
  register: conf_file

- name: 'Start server'
  service:
    name: my_server
    state: restarted
  when: conf_file.changed
```

This *sometimes* fails with the server claiming that the configuration file does not exist, on a first run (initial install, not rerunning the Playbook.)  If I have Ansible wait for awhile before starting the server, everything works fine.

Why would this happen with Ansible SSH pipelining turned on?